# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error

Tags: php, foreach, arguments

I'm getting this error just after installing a childtheme for thematic. The child theme is Crystalline.

The error is:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in crystalline/footer.php on line 3

In `footer.php` I have this:

```
<?php
global $options;
foreach ($options as $value) {
  if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = $value['std']; }
  else { $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] ); }
 }
?>
</div><!-- #main -->

<?php thematic_abovefooter(); ?>    

<div id="footer">
    <?php get_sidebar('subsidiary'); ?>
    <div id="siteinfo">        
        <?php /* footer text set in theme options */ echo   
     stripslashes($thm_footertext); ?>
        <br/><a href="http://www.reflectionmedia.ro/blog/">Crystalline  
     Child Theme</a>
    </div><!-- #siteinfo -->
</div><!-- #footer -->

 </div><!-- #wrapper .hfeed -->

 <?php wp_footer() ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What is the value of $options? Is that an array?

Comment: [Take a look at this ;)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style)

Answer (score 2):

```
$options
```

Probably is not array or object.

Check it with:

```
var_dump($options);
```

Comment: Ok, I recognize I don't know how to read the code, so don't really get what you're telling me. The problem is in line 3, should I replace that line with var_dump($options); ? Thanks

Comment: No, it`s not. It`s need to be placed just after `global $options`, before `foreach`. This line will provide details of variable `options`. I guess one of your database queries failed. If `options` is not `array` or `object` then it may be a problem. If you made some changes in database queries, then it might be a cause of this behaviour.